# Get a function's callback to return a value to parent function

Tags: javascript, events, node.js, callback

I'm developing a node.js app. What I'm trying to do is get the `getBody()` function to return the body of response the URL. The way I've written this would obviously only return the request function and not what the request function returns. I wrote that to show where I'm stuck.

```
var request = require('request');

var Body = function(url) {
  this.url = url;
};

Body.prototype.getBody = function() {
   return request({url:this.url}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
      console.log('Could not fetch the URL', error);
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return body;
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `request` function is *asynchronous*, you won't be able to return the result of the request.

What you can do is have the `getBody` function receive a callback function that is invoked when the response is received.

```
Body.prototype.getBody = function (callback) {
    request({
        url: this.url
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
            console.log('Could not fetch the URL', error);
        } else {
            callback(body); // invoke the callback function, and pass the body
        }
    });
};
```

So you'd use it like this...

```
var body_inst = new Body('http://example.com/some/path'); // create a Body object

  // invoke the getBody, and pass a callback that will be passed the response
body_inst.getBody(function( body ) {

    console.log(body);  // received the response body

});
```

Comment: Kinda confused. Shouldn't I get rid of the `return` before `request()`?

Comment: @JungleHunter: Oh yeah, no need for the `return` anymore. Glad it worked.